# Show Next part of String in new line if string contains comma

Tags: c#, string

I am working on a project where I need Display text in label like

```
1 year amount 2000
2 year amount 4000
```

& I am getting the data from table as

> 1 year amount 2000,2 year amount 4000,3 year amount 6000.

I need to display data in 3 rows. Like this:

```
1 year amount 2000
2 year amount 4000
3 year amount 6000.
```

Comment: Do you have any code showing what you have tried/working with?

Comment: No dear i dont have any code for this..I just want simple logic so i can try it on my own.

Comment: try to do replace `string.Replace(",", "\n");`

Answer (score 1):

If you split your string on the comma then you'll get an array of entries:

```
string input = "1 year amount 2000,2 year amount 4000";
string[] parts = input.Split(',');
```

You can then display that array in a list box or grid for example. Without knowing exactly how you want to display the data it's difficult to suggest what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

```
        string input = "1 year amount 2000,2 year amount 4000";
        List<string> parts = input.Split(',').ToList();
        if (parts != null && parts.Any())
        {
            parts.ForEach((s) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            });
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Use the above code and modify as per your need.

Comment: @Manprit..Thankss dude :)